# In Angular, What does it mean $location.path() == '/a'?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJs and I am going through Angular documentation to understand it. I recently encountered this this code   `$location.path() == '/a'`, but I fail to understand what does it mean and what it does. In this example `==` is used as a assignment operator? So can anyone explain me what difference will it make? Is it angular specific or it means something in Javascript as well.

```
    it('should show example', inject(
  function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
  },
  function($location) {
    // open http://example.com/base/index.html#!/a
    $location.absUrl() == 'http://example.com/base/index.html#!/a'
    $location.path() == '/a'

    $location.path('/foo')
    $location.absUrl() == 'http://example.com/base/index.html#!/foo'

    $location.search() == {}
    $location.search({a: 'b', c: true});
    $location.absUrl() == 'http://example.com/base/index.html#!/foo?a=b&c'

    $location.path('/new').search('x=y');
    $location.absUrl() == 'http://example.com/base/index.html#!/new?x=y'
  }
));
```

This entire code is [from the angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location).

Comment: Since when is `==` the assignment operator?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just showing you that in hashBang mode if you have the url http://example.com/base/index.html#!/a

`$location.absUrl()` will be `'http://example.com/base/index.html#!/a'`

(i.e. `$location.absUrl() == 'http://example.com/base/index.html#!/a'` is `true`)

Same with `$location.path()` will be `'/a'`

(`$location.path() == '/a'` is `true`)

Comment: So what purpose does it solve in this example? I understand it is checking something, but it is not using its outcome. Can you give me some example to explain?

Comment: @Prateek **It's an illustrative sample in the manual**, it's not supposed to be real code.

Comment: @Prateek exactly as deceze said, it's not meant to do anything, just to show you what would happen.